# Selenium: Difference between by Value and by Visible Text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Can somebody please tell me what is the difference between selectByValue and selectByVisibleText methods in Selenium for selecting an item from the dropdown menu?

Comment: You should google this question. You could look at the Selenium docs or any one of hundreds of Selenium tutorial sites or books or blogs or ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

selectByValue will return all options with a value property set that matches your parameter ex:

**java:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Countries"));
Select s = new Select(element);
s.selectByValue("america");
```

**html:**

```
<select name="Countries"><option selectd> Please select</option>
  <option value="brasil">Brazil</option>
  <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
  <option value="am">America</option>
  <option value="america">United States</option>
</select>
```

this will select: `<option value="america">United States</option>`

selectByVisibleText all options that display text matching the given argument:

**java:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Countries"));
Select s = new Select(element);
s.selectByVisibleText("Brasil");
```

**html:**

```
<select name="Countries"><option selectd> Please select</option>
  <option value="brasil">Brasil</option>
  <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
  <option value="am">America</option>
  <option value="america">United States</option>
</select>
```

this will select: `<option value="br">Brasil</option>`

Comment: `se.selectByVisibleText("Brasil");` This will select nothing since the text is Bra**z**il ;)

Comment: Small typo... fixed

Answer (score 1):

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-select-methods-to-work-with-dropdowns

This gave detailed explanation.If u used selectbyvalue it will select based on attribute 'value'

If you used selectbyVisibleText it will select based on the innertext of the option tag.